# Viewing all run parameters of a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a running docker container which is started by someone else using `docker run ...`.

Is it possible to list all the parameters of `docker run` of this container?

I've tried `docker inspect <container_id>` to get the information of the container. But I'm not sure how to correctly convert the results of `docker inspect` to the parameters of `docker run`.

Comment: Prevention is better than cure. If you use `docker-compose` to start your jobs then the compose file documents all the options you needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [**nexdrew/rekcod**](https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod):

> A simple module to reverse engineer a docker run command from an existing container (via docker inspect).
>   Just pass in the container names or ids that you want to reverse engineer and `rekcod` will output a `docker run` command that duplicates the container.

```
$ npm i -g rekcod

# single container
$ rekcod container-name

docker run --name container-name ...
```

Of course, as [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5209935/matthew) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116710/viewing-all-run-parameters-of-a-docker-container#comment65581831_39116710), [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) helps specifying the exact parameters you need for your containers.
Or at least version with your sources scripts which are launching your container with `docker run` commands (if you don't use docker-compose).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying if rekcod works in my case now :-)

Comment: @lyen Sure, let us (me and other readers) know how it turns out in your case.